# Changing drop down icon bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm wanting to try change the **default arrow on the bootstrap dropdown menu button**? Is this possible at all? I'm hoping to make it something like the android spinner icon:

[image]

Otherwise, just something from FontAwesome or something. I don't want to use jQuery / I *have to use* Bootstrap dropdowns:
http://getbootstrap.com/components/#dropdowns

I found a lot of questions similar to what I'm asking but that were more closely linked to jQuery - but if a solution already exists feel free to point me to it.

Comment: yes you can. but not for all browers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course you can. Just replace span with class "caret" into something else and play with css a bit. Instead of:

```
<button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true">
Dropdown
<span class="caret"></span>
</button>
```

use:

```
<button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true">
Dropdown
<i class="fa fa-external-link"></i>
</button>
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/6140/)

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much - I also now understand what the span was there for.

Answer (score 0):

I had nearly the identical question but was looking for a pure CSS solution (sprinkled with some FontAwesome) against the `.caret` selector. Found my way [fiddling around](https://jsfiddle.net/mpw39g9k/7/) with the `:before` pseudo-element.

```
.caret {
  border: none;
}

.caret:before {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  content: "\f019";
  position: relative;
  top: -9px;
}
```